# Show Shipping Method data on the Order edit pages in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders

In WooCommerce on [this website](https://stage.helium2go.com.au), I have 2 Local Pickup shipping methods:

- AM pickup: `shipping_method_0_local_pickup31`
- PM pickup: `shipping_method_0_local_pickup32`

Unfortunately this shipping method does not show up on Admin Order edit pages

Is is possible to use:

```
add_action('woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_shipping_address','cwn_add_pickup_to_order_item_meta', 1, 2);

function cwn_add_pickup_to_order_item_meta($shipping_method) {
    echo "<h4>Pickup Time</h4>";
    echo '<p><strong>' . __('AM pickup') . ':</strong><br> ' .   get_post_meta($shipping_method->id, '_shipping_method_0_local_pickup31', true) . '</p>';
    echo '<p><strong>' . __('PM pickup') . ':</strong><br> ' . get_post_meta($shipping_method->id, '_shipping_method_0_local_pickup32', true) . '</p>';
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is 2 similar ways to get the Shipping methods data in the WC_Order object.

1) Using **`WC_Abstract_Order`** [**`get_shipping_methods()`**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Abstract_Order.html#_get_shipping_methods) method.
2) Using **`WC_Abstract_Order`** [**`get_items( 'shipping' )`**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Abstract_Order.html#_get_items) method.

This will output an array of [**`WC_Order_Item_Shipping`**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Order_Item_Shipping.html) objects. So you will need a foreach loop to use **`WC_Order_Item_Shipping`** methods to get the data, this way *(Where **`$order`** is an instance of the **`WC_Order`** object)*:

```
foreach($order->get_items( 'shipping' ) as $shipping_method ){
    $method_id = $shipping_method->get_method_id().'<br>';
    $shipping_method_name = $shipping_method->get_name().'<br>';
    $shipping_method_title = $shipping_method->get_method_title().'<br>';
    $shipping_method_total = $shipping_method->get_total().'<br>';
    $shipping_method_total_tax = $shipping_method->get_total_tax().'<br>';
}

//Or:

foreach($order->get_shipping_methods() as $shipping_method ){
    $method_id = $shipping_method->get_method_id().'<br>';
    $shipping_method_name = $shipping_method->get_name().'<br>';
    $shipping_method_title = $shipping_method->get_method_title().'<br>';
    $shipping_method_total = $shipping_method->get_total().'<br>';
    $shipping_method_total_tax = $shipping_method->get_total_tax().'<br>';
}
```

> In your code, the **`$shipping_method`** hooked function argument is wrong as it should be **`$order`** (an instance of **`WC_Order object`**.

So now you can use it in your hooked function, this way for example:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_shipping_address', 'cwn_add_pickup_to_order_item_meta', 10, 1 );
function cwn_add_pickup_to_order_item_meta( $order ){
    echo '<div>';
    foreach($order->get_shipping_methods() as $shipping_method ){
        echo '<p><strong>Shipping Method ID:</strong> '. $shipping_method->get_method_id().'<br>
        <strong>Shipping Method name:</strong> '. $shipping_method->get_name().'<br>
        <strong>Shipping Method title:</strong> '. $shipping_method->get_method_title().'<br>
        <strong>Shipping Method Total:</strong> '. $shipping_method->get_total().'<br>
        <strong>Shipping Method Total tax:</strong> '. $shipping_method->get_total_tax().'</p><br>';
    }
    echo '</div>';
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file*

Tested and works on WooCommerce 3+

Comment: Works like a charm Thank you Loic TheAztec

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a way to ***execute a command*** when finalizing a purchase and the shipping method selected was different from "***LOCAL PICKUP***".

Your last code gave me the light I needed.
My code worked.

**Follow my code to help whoever needs it:**

```
function showpopup($order_id){
    $order = wc_get_order($order_id);
    $order->get_shipping_methods(); 
    if( ! $order->has_shipping_method('local_pickup') ) {
    
        echo '
<script>
function myFunction() {
  alert("Retirada no local NÃO SELECIONADA!");
}
myFunction()
</script>
        ';
    
    }
}   
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'showpopup', 10, 1 );
```

**Thank you.**